# JavaScript library to help manage dialog stacks?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, dialog

In our app we are solving the problem with dialog hierarchies. Consider following example: the user opens a dialog (list of objects) then another one from within the first one (say a detail) and then the next one (say a date picker from the dialog).

What should happen when users click outside dialog bounds?

- Should the topmost dialog be closed and cancelled?
- Should the whole stack of dialogs be cancelled?
- Or, if the click target opens a completely different stack of dialogs (list of projects in the app), should both stacks be open at the same time?

These are all very real use cases and while I see many smallish libraries doing absolutely positioned overlays (like jQuery UI) I don't see anything to help manage more complex dialog workflows. At the moment we don't have a systematic way of solving those, we're mostly ifing on a case by case basis, which is very error prone. Please, suggest a solution, a library or at least some code/project to get inspiration from.

Answer (score 0):

Look for source code of ZIndexManager or anything similar in any framework, trying to simulate desktop UX (e.g. ExtJS), in order to get the idea.

jQuery and its plugins are created for lightweight web interfaces w/o dozens of stacking windows.